# vbscript match within a match

Tags: regex, vbscript, pattern-matching

Good day all.

I am running some Cisco show commands on a router.  I am capturing the output to an array.  I want to use Regex to find certain information in the output.  The Regex works in the sense that it find the line containing it however there is not enough unique information I can create my regex with so I end up with more that I want.  Here is the output:

```
 ROUTERNAME#sh diag 
Slot 0:
        C2821 Motherboard with 2GE and integrated VPN Port adapter, 2 ports
        Port adapter is analyzed 
        Port adapter insertion time 18w4d ago
        Onboard VPN             : v2.3.3
        EEPROM contents at hardware discovery:
        PCB Serial Number        : FOC1XXXXXXXXX
        Hardware Revision        : 1.0
        Top Assy. Part Number    : 800-26921-04
        Board Revision           : E0
        Deviation Number         : 0
        Fab Version              : 03
        RMA Test History         : 00
        RMA Number               : 0-0-0-0
        RMA History              : 00
        Processor type           : 87 
        Hardware date code       : 20090816
        Chassis Serial Number    : FTXXXXXXXXXX
        Chassis MAC Address      : 0023.ebf4.5480
        MAC Address block size   : 32
        CLEI Code                : COMV410ARA
        Product (FRU) Number     : CISCO2821      
        Part Number              : 73-8853-05
        Version Identifier       : V05 
        EEPROM format version 4
        EEPROM contents (hex):
          0x00: 04 FF C1 8B 46 4F 43 31 33 33 33 31 4E 36 34 40
          0x10: 03 E8 41 01 00 C0 46 03 20 00 69 29 04 42 45 30
          0x20: 88 00 00 00 00 02 03 03 00 81 00 00 00 00 04 00
          0x30: 09 87 83 01 32 8F C0 C2 8B 46 54 58 31 33 33 36
          0x40: 41 30 4C 41 C3 06 00 23 EB F4 54 80 43 00 20 C6
          0x50: 8A 43 4F 4D 56 34 31 30 41 52 41 CB 8F 43 49 53
          0x60: 43 4F 32 38 32 31 20 20 20 20 20 20 82 49 22 95
          0x70: 05 89 56 30 35 20 D9 02 40 C1 FF FF FF FF FF FF

AIM Module in slot: 0
        Hardware Revision        : 1.0
        Top Assy. Part Number    : 800-27059-01
        Board Revision           : A0
        Deviation Number         : 0-0
        Fab Version              : 02
        PCB Serial Number        : FOXXXXXXXXX
        RMA Test History         : 00
        RMA Number               : 0-0-0-0
        RMA History              : 00
        Product (FRU) Number     : AIM-VPN/SSL-2
        Version Identifier       : V01
        EEPROM format version 4
        EEPROM contents (hex):
          0x00: 04 FF 40 04 F4 41 01 00 C0 46 03 20 00 69 B3 01
          0x10: 42 41 30 80 00 00 00 00 02 02 C1 8B 46 4F 43 31
          0x20: 33 33 31 36 39 59 55 03 00 81 00 00 00 00 04 00
          0x30: CB 8D 41 49 4D 2D 56 50 4E 2F 53 53 4C 2D 32 89
          0x40: 56 30 31 00 D9 02 40 C1 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x50: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x60: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
          0x70: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

What I want to capture is the Model number that is contained in the 'Product (FRU) Number:' section.  In this example 'CISCO2821'.  I want to output or MsgBox just the CISCO2821 although other possibilities could be 'CISCO2911/K9' or something similar.

This is the regex pattern I am using:

```
Product\s\(FRU\)\sNumber\s*:\s*CIS.*
```

Using a regex testing tool I was able to match the entire line containing what I want but I want to write only the model number.

I looked at 'ltrim' and 'rtrim' but did not think that could do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is in VB.NET not vbscript, but this may help get you on your way:

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("Product\s\(FRU\)\sNumber[\s\t]+:\s(CIS.+?)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
ResultString = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString).Groups(1).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Invest in 2 little helper functions:

```
Function qq(sT) : qq = """" & sT & """" : End Function

Function newRE(sP, sF)
  Set newRE = New RegExp
  newRE.Pattern = sP
  newRE.Global     = "G" = Mid(sF, 1, 1)
  newRE.IgnoreCase = "I" = Mid(sF, 2, 1)
  newRE.MultiLine  = "M" = Mid(sF, 3, 1)
End Function
```

and use

```
  ' 3 ways to skin this cat
  Dim sInp : sInp = Join(Array( _
      "CLEI Code: COMV410ARA" _
    , "Product (FRU) Number : CISCO2821" _
    , "Part Number:73-8853-05" _
  ), vbCrLf) ' or vbLf, vbCr 
  WScript.Echo sInp
  ' (1) just search for CIS + sequence of non-spaces - risky if e.g. CLEI Code starts with CIS
  WScript.Echo 0, "=>", qq(newRE("CIS\S+", "gim").Execute(sInp)(0).Value)
  ' (2) use a capture/group (idea stolen from skyburner; just 'ported' to VBScript)
  WScript.Echo 1, "=>", qq(newRE("\(FRU\)[^:]+:\s(\S+)", "gim").Execute(sInp)(0).Value)
  WScript.Echo 2, "=>", qq(newRE("\(FRU\)[^:]+:\s(\S+)", "gim").Execute(sInp)(0).SubMatches(0))
  ' (3) generalize & use a Dictionary
  Dim dicProps : Set dicProps = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim oMT
  For Each oMT in newRe("^\s*(.+?)\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*$", "GiM").Execute(sInp)
      Dim oSM : Set oSM = oMT.SubMatches
      dicProps(oSM(0)) = oSM(1)
  Next
  Dim sName
  For Each sName In dicProps.Keys
      WScript.Echo qq(sName), "=>", qq(dicProps(sName))
  Next
```

to get this output:

```
CLEI Code: COMV410ARA
Product (FRU) Number : CISCO2821
Part Number:73-8853-05
0 => "CISCO2821"
1 => "(FRU) Number : CISCO2821"
2 => "CISCO2821"
"CLEI Code" => "COMV410ARA"
"Product (FRU) Number" => "CISCO2821"
"Part Number" => "73-8853-05"
```

and - I hope - some food for thought.

Important

1. a (plain) pattern matches/finds some part of the input
2. captures/groups/submatches/parentheses cut parts from this match
3. sometimes dealing with a generalized version of the problem gives
   you more gain for less work